# fixed div on bottom of page that stops in given place

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have fixed div on bottom of my page that works well. I wonder if there is some simple way to make it "stop" on some place in page when user srolls down to it. I want it to remain fixed on bottom, until user scrolls down to some defined place on page and than stick it to the page and scroll like the rest of content. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you perhaps mean (a modification of) what is done on Chromium's issues pages? (e.g. http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=75) Note the left pane which stays visible when you scroll down. If I'm not mistaking, you'd like to have it slightly different but hopefully it helps you.

Comment: yes it looks like something i could use.. i will look into it maybe i can make it work the way i need. Thanks for reply!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I tried setting something up on jsfiddle. While I was writing it up, I see that others have posted their alternatives. In case mine helps in any way: http://jsfiddle.net/PnUmM/1/

I set the position to relative in the CSS, calculate where it is on document load to keep the info aside and then set it to fixed.

```
var sticky_offset;
$(document).ready(function() {

    var original_position_offset = $('#sticky_for_a_while').offset();
    sticky_offset = original_position_offset.top;
    $('#sticky_for_a_while').css('position', 'fixed');


});

$(window).scroll(function () {
    var sticky_height = $('#sticky_for_a_while').outerHeight();
    var where_scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    var window_height = $(window).height();


    if((where_scroll + window_height) > sticky_offset) {
        $('#sticky_for_a_while').css('position', 'relative');
    }

    if((where_scroll + window_height) < (sticky_offset + sticky_height))  {
        $('#sticky_for_a_while').css('position', 'fixed');
    }

});
```

Comment: yes the answers come very quickly here :-) but anyway thanks for trying i thing i got the idea

Comment: ok i finally found time to try this, i had to re-write it to pure js because i cannot use jQuerry on this, but it works like charm now. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, this works for me too.. however, instead of attching to the bottom, I need to attach it to the top of the screen when scrolling page down.. any idea?

Answer (score 2):

I made this up for you: http://jsfiddle.net/XCYFG/1/.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    window._div1 = $('#div1'); //selector is expensive
    window._window = $(window);
    $(window).scroll(function(e) {
        _div1.css("top",
                  Math.min(_window.height(),
                           window.scrollY + 100)
                  + _window.height() - _div1.height() - 110);
    }).scroll();
});
```

Comment: this looks cool, but can i controll it with position of another div? I mean like - when i scroll down to see "that" div, start scrolling this one? From brief look at your code the moment when div start scrolling is defined in pixels, but i will have different amount of content on every page so i need to adjust it every time... but on second thought, i can get position of that div by js and than insert the value to your script is that right?

Answer (score 1):

I have a plugin that does the opposite - it's in the flow of the webpage, and when the user scrolls past it, it gets fixed to the viewport. What it actually does though is apply a css class to the element, so you should be able to use it as is.

You can find the plugin here:
https://github.com/hanssonlarsson/jquery-fixedscroll

Then I would suggest you have your element in the flow of your webpage:

```
<div id="sometimesFixed">content</div>
```

With css:

```
#sometimesFixed {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}
#sometimesFixed.scroll {
  position: static;
}
```

And apply the plugin like so, in your JavaScript:

```
$('#sometimesFixed').fixedscroll({className: 'scroll'});
```

There is also a more general plugin, very new, called jquery-waypoints. The idea is to bind any code to "waypoints", points on the webpage where, when the user scrolls past them, some code is executed.

https://github.com/imakewebthings/jquery-waypoints

It's probably more optimized and a better fit than my plugin, but YMMV!

Comment: Nice, but i am afraid i cannot use jquery this time, we dont use it in our project. I have to find a way to do it with dojo or pure js. But thanks anyway!