# Floating DIV in bottom of the page (it shouldn't scroll after footer DIV)

Tags: html, css

```
div{
   position:fixed;
   bottom:0px;
   height:20px;
}
```

in above code explains that will always keep the DIV in bottom. but i need to avoid the scroll after the footer. i meant need to set boundary for the floating div.

Can you help me?

> [Edited] Please refer this and help me!
>   http://jsfiddle.net/umarfaruk/y9cWf/ i added my sample in that. how
>   can i stop floating div when we touch footer div. (i meant the
>   floating should stop scrolling before the footer)

**UPDATED:**

Thank you guys. i found the solution at http://jsfiddle.net/PnUmM/1 Really thanks to @Gatekeeper :)

Comment: can you give an example in http://jsfiddle.net/ for understand better

Comment: you can insert an empty div after `footer` which height is `20px`

Comment: how is any of this related to jquery ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/umarfaruk/y9cWf/ i added my sample in that. how can i stop #floating div when we touch #footer div. (i meant the #floating should stop scrolling before the #footer)

Comment: I had same question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5141425/fixed-div-on-bottom-of-page-that-stops-in-given-place little modification and it works like a charm ;-)

Comment: dude you could really accept one of the answers from below...

Answer (score 1):

Like [Giberno](https://stackoverflow.com/users/964076/giberno) wrote in his comment, use an empty div to fill up the space  occupied by the footer (and thus preventing the last line(s) of text falling being hidden by the footer. Nice and easy: No scripts required!

```
div#footer{
   position:fixed;
   bottom:0px;
   height:20px;
}

div#empty-space{
   height:20px; /* Same height as footer */
}
```

And the HTML:

```
Put your page here
...
<div id="empty-space"/>
<div id="footer">footer</div>
```

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/veger/e4AUL/) for a working example.

Comment: Thank you guys. i found the solution at http://jsfiddle.net/PnUmM/1/ Really thanks to @Gatekeeper :)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing to do is to give the `body` a bottom padding the same height as the fixed element. That way you will always be able to scroll to any content.

```
#body {
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}
#fixed {
    height: 50px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
```

[here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9UDSD/1/)

Answer (score 0):

write in your page or stylesheet to avoid scrollbar after f

```
* {
 margin: 0 auto;
}
```