# Fix multiple divs on the bottom of page until I scroll to a certain point

Tags: jquery, css-position

I'm trying to have multiple divs -stacked on top of each other- fixed on the bottom. After some scrolling I would like to "release" one after another div.

You can find the base code here: http://jsfiddle.net/krafna/vV3nP/31/

```
<div id="open-page">WELCOME PAGE<br>please scroll down</div>
<div id="container">
<div id="top-pag1">1</div>
<div id="pag1"></div>

<div id="top-pag2">2</div>
<div id="pag2"></div>

<div id="top-pag3">3</div>
<div id="pag3"></div>

<div id="top-pag4">4</div>
<div id="pag4"></div>
```

I'm trying to fix all #top-pag and when it reaches the #pag it would be released.
I already tried a solution proposed by [isotrop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5141425/fixed-div-on-bottom-of-page-that-stops-in-given-place), but the problem is to do this with multiple divs. I tried some other jQuery but I couldn't edit it with success -I'm still new at this.

I think this image will help to understand my objective: [example](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7189869/EXAMPLE.png) 
Thank you all.

Comment: Is this anything close to what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/tKeYe/ (no JS required)...

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this

```
var toppag=$("#top-pag1,#top-pag2,#top-pag3,#top-pag4");
var pag=$("#pag1,#pag2,#pag3,#pag4");
toppag.css({position:"fixed",bottom:"0px"});
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var scroll=$(this).scrollTop()+$(this).height();
    pag.each(function(i,n){
        if(scroll > $(this).offset().top) {
            toppag.eq(i).css({'position':'relative'});
            if(i>0){
                 toppag.eq(i).css({'top':i*-50});
            }
        }
        if(scroll < ($(this).offset().top + toppag.eq(i).height()))  {
            toppag.eq(i).css({'position':'fixed',"top":""});
        }
    }); 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vV3nP/34/
if all $("#pag1,#pag2,#pag3,#pag4") have the same height 50px you can set all $("#top-pag1,#top-pag2,#top-pag3,#top-pag4") css top:-50px and margin-bottom:-50px so you dont have to set in the css values like -50px, -100px

```
var toppag=$("#top-pag1,#top-pag2,#top-pag3,#top-pag4");
var pag=$("#pag1,#pag2,#pag3,#pag4");
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var scroll=$(this).scrollTop()+$(this).height();
    pag.each(function(i,n){
        if(scroll > $(this).offset().top) {
             toppag.eq(i).css({'position':'relative',"top":"-50px","margin-bottom":"-50px"});
        }
        else if(scroll < ($(this).offset().top + toppag.eq(i).height()))  {
            toppag.eq(i).css({'position':'fixed',"top":"","margin-bottom":""});
        }
    }); 
});
```

and the css like this

```
#pag2{
    background:#565656;
} 
#pag3{
    background:#000;
}
#pag4{
    background:#FF6258;
}
#top-pag1, #top-pag2, #top-pag3, #top-pag4{
    height:50px; position:fixed;bottom:0px;
}
#top-pag1{
    background:#8AC14D;
    width:250px;
} 
#top-pag2{
    background:#565656; 
    width:200px; 
} 
#top-pag3{
    background:#000; 
    color:#FFF; 
    width:150px;
}
#top-pag4{
    background:#FF6258; 
    width:50px; 
}
```

fixed jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vV3nP/37/

Comment: Thanks. That is what I wanted. I just wanted to know if it's possible to "pick up" #top-pag from the bottom of the div. It seems that it only stops to be fixed when the #pag pass the #top-pag. I hope the question is clear...

Comment: to "pick up" the top-pag it needs to have the "else if" inside each on the second example on the last fiddle and remove the  "if(i>0){" to position all top-pag to -50px you can check the edited answer

Comment: Nice and smooth. Thanks!