# Zurb Foundation 4 scrolling 2 divs

Tags: jquery, html, css, zurb-foundation

I'm using Zurb Foundation 4 for a website.

The following problem was encountered:

2 div-boxes with text content, `div.text_left` have much more content then `div.text_right`.

If i scroll down and the end of `div.text_right` is reached, `div.text_right` should stop and only the `div.text_left` box should scroll further.

Anyone knows a solution?

http://jsfiddle.net/robce/yrfB5/

Here is the code:

```
    <!-- Nav Bar -->
<div class="contain-to-grid sticky">
    <nav class="top-bar">
        <ul class="title-area">
            <!-- Title Area -->
            <li class="name">
                <h1><a href="#">Marimba </a></h1>
            </li>
            <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span>Menu</span></a></li>
        </ul>

        <section class="top-bar-section">
            <!-- Left Nav Section -->
            <ul class="left">
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li class="active"><a href="#">ACCOMODATION</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">ACTIVITIES</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">MOZAMBIQUE</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
            </ul>

            <!-- Right Nav Section -->
            <ul class="right">
                <li class="divider hide-for-small"></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li class="divider show-for-small"></li>
            </ul>
        </section>
    </nav>
</div>
<!-- End Nav -->


<div class="row full">
    <div id="primary">
        <div class="large-8 columns text_left">
            <div class="panel">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.....
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="large-4 columns text_right">
            <div class="panel">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor...
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not against using Javascript for the solution, here are some options: [fixed div on bottom of page that stops in given place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5141425/fixed-div-on-bottom-of-page-that-stops-in-given-place).

There's a guy on here with a Github plugin that has exactly what you're looking for, plus everyone else has some JS that could be used for what you want.

Otherwise, I'm not sure Foundation has what you're looking for.  I've worked with Foundation before and their JS plugins don't seem to have anything like this.

Looking at your Fiddle, it doesn't appear that you can apply `position: fixed;` to the element itself, since you won't be able to scroll it at all.  I think JS is the best option here.

Comment: Thanks for your help and the link! The solution of "isotope" going in the right direction.. 
problem: It would be perfect as soon as the scrollbar has arrived the end of **div.text_right**. **div.text_right** should stop immediately and remains at the actually position. **div.text_left** box should scroll further… [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/robce/VRX6D/)

Comment: Try messing around with this code: jsfiddle.net/VRX6D/2. If you can get the idea of what I'm trying to do, it might help to combine some of this with some of your existing code (this does not work, just wanted to see if the ideas would help you at all).

Comment: Thanks for your help! After some trial and error finally i came across this solution:[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VRX6D/21/)